# Lightning RefreshView event does not update the Sales Path on Opportunity Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, refresh

I have an Opportunity Page with Standard Sales Path component and a custom lightning component. I update the stage from APEX and in lightning controller callback, I call the e.force:refreshView. But for some reason the page refresh is called before the update. So the sales path is not updated and show the old value of Opportunity stage. Please refer the code

```
var action = component.get("c.updateOpportunity");
action.setParams({ "oppId" : component.get("v.recordId"), "oppStageName" : 
newStage });
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
var state = response.getState();
if(state === "SUCCESS") {
component.set("v.record.StageName",response.getReturnValue().StageName);
$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
}else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
```

Comment: I think this issue has to do with the following known issue : https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001CqpQAE&title=sales-path-not-refreshing-with-process-builder-or-workflow-rules.  , though it says process builders and workflow rules. I think it is suitable for any automated process updates.

Comment: If it helps anyone, we raised the case with SF support for this bug and now the above code works just fine.